# How to add printers to Ubuntu en masse

Tags: printing, batch

I work at a company with many network printers. We're switching many of our computers to Ubuntu 13.04 and I need to add the printers en masse. I figured the best way to do that was through a script. This is an example line to add a printer:

```
lpadmin -p printername -E -v socket://ip.address -m ppd
```

This adds a printer, but it fails to load the required ppd file. When I search for a ppd file, many of the links I find redirect me to a program called hplip, which apparently serves as a printer driver? But how do I reference those ppd's from a script file?

Here's the specific error I'm getting:

```
lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file.
```

Comment: Are these all the same printer type? [`hplip`](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) has the HP printer drivers. I also think you need to the `-P` option to specify the file in `/usr/share/ppd/...`, not `-m`.... For more info, run `man lpadmin`.

Comment: /usr/share/ppd/ seems to not contain any .ppd files. There is a directory /usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP that contains fax machine ppds, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I'll try -P and get back to you. Can you give an example line using hplip?